# How to implement android navigation drawer?

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I want to implement the android navigation drawer for my app that is supporting jellybean and higher. All tutorials I seen so far use the support version.

I am wondering, are they doing that to support people who want to support old android versions?

If possible I want to use the non-support version. Does anyone know where I can find a good tutorial for that?

Or is using the support version the only way to get it?

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Thanks

Comment: That support library can be used in latest versions also...

Comment: Yeah, but then I have to import the google support thing right?

Comment: AFAIK, that library is available in Android SDK. see in `android-sdk/extras/android/support/v4`. Just add that jar file to your project build path

Comment: But other things like action bar has a support and non support version too right (with a different api code), even the gridlayout, I want to know if the nagivation drawer has a non support version too...

Comment: Once open [android](http://developer.android.com/index.html) developer site and start typing `DrawerLayout` in search box. This will show classes from support library only. Means there is no non-support version...

Answer (score 0):

The [docs for the Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html) states:

> The Android Support Library package is a set of code libraries that
>   provide backward-compatible versions of Android framework APIs **as well
>   as features that are only available through the library APIs**.

This means that this library contains components, which are not included in the Android SDK. F.e. the ViewPager and related classes like the family of PagerAdapters or even the DrawerLayout.